# How to get everything before and after @ in string

Tags: javascript

I would like to get everything after and before the @ in a string. For example, the string:

`foo user@google.com foo`,

I would like to get the whole string before @ and after the @. Thank you in advance

I want to get `user@google.com`, and remove foo and foo from the string using the @

Comment: `'string1@string2'.split( '@' )`

Comment: `str.split('@')` will give you an array with those strings.

Comment: @andy that does not answer my question sorry, I would like to get everything before and after the whitespace of the @

Comment: @AidenKaiser You are clearly not asking it correctly then. Sounds like you want to parse/extract an email address from a string...

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like this:

```js
var str = "foo aUser@example.com foo";
str = str.split(" ")[1];
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Not what I am asking, sorry, I want to get the string `user@google.com` and remove foo and foo from the string.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much